# how to make zurb foundation print as they show in the browser

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I want to print the page as it shows in the browser.

Most images break during printing when page has few images for example

http://jsfiddle.net/V7TuY/4/

http://fiddle.jshell.net/V7TuY/4/show/

In above example if you will try print preview you will see image will take who row rather than showing rather than showing as a single row.

How to fix this kind on issues

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="small-12 medium-2 medium-offset-1 columns">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/480x600&text=[img 1]" />
    </div>
    <div class="small-12 medium-2 columns">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/480x600&text=[img 1]" />
    </div>
    <div class="small-12 medium-2 columns">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/480x600&text=[img 1]" />
    </div>
    <div class="small-12 medium-2 columns">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/480x600&text=[img 1]" />
    </div>
    <div class="small-12 medium-2 columns end">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/480x600&text=[img 1]" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You, probably, will have to build Foundation from sass and override media queries.

Comment: cant we override without sass.

Comment: It will be harder. There are tons of generated media query rules.

Comment: I work on .net i am not sure how to work & compile sass so to include in my project

Comment: You can try auto replacing word `screen` with `all` and `print` with something obscure like `braille` in the Foundation css just to test what happens. It should work.

Comment: I tried this option didn't work. i even replace `only screen` with `screen, print` even this didn't work, isn't there a foundation.css file without print option or a separate css file to overwrite print option of zurb foundation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick way to do this is to add overriding styles like these:

```
@media print {
  .large-1 {
    width: 8.33333%;
  }

  .large-2 {
    width: 16.66667%;
  }

  .large-3 {
    width: 25%;
  }

  etc.....
}
```

The default Foundation grid is 12 columns wide, so 1/12 roughly equals 8.33333% and you can use that to calculate how wide each class should be.

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/jordan90/uNjLu/3/

The main reason I wanted to answer though is because I don't have enough reputation to comment, and I wanted to let you know how to work with SASS in .NET.

There's an extension for Visual Studio called SassyStudio that compiles CSS files from SASS for you every time you save a SASS file. I have tried numerous options and SassyStudio is the easiest way to get up and running with SASS in Visual Studio. If you combine that with a NuGet package like Foundation5.MVC.Sass that sets up all of the Foundation and SASS for you, it lets you start using Foundation with SASS in Visual Studio very quickly.

Comment: Thank you, This did the trick, I will work on your advice and try to work with `SassyStudio`. Just wanted to know if i can use `Foundation5.MVC.Sass` with asp.net webforms as i am working with webforms not MVC.

Comment: The MVC Foundation package won't work with Web Forms, but there is one with just the SASS files that I just tested with a Web Forms project and it looks like it should work for you: [https://www.nuget.org/packages/Foundation5.Core.Sass/](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Foundation5.Core.Sass/).